# jQuery file upload preview image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), everything is working apart from the image preview before upload.

I added all the JS files like the demo and the same JS.ie footer:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/load-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/plugins/upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/plugins/upload/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/plugins/upload/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/plugins/upload/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/plugins/upload/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery/plugins/upload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/flatui/flatui-checkbox.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/backend.upload.js"></script>
```

In the upload JS I have:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'photos',
        maxFileSize: 5000000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    });

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );


        // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done').call(this, null, {result: result});
    });

});
```

And here is a GIST of the HTML:  https://gist.github.com/weblee/6449018

Im getting no console errors either. Any advise?

Here it is in progress: http://screencast.com/t/HPQgdUsW

Comment: I find that jQuery will hide errors in most cases. You may need to throw a bunch of console.log commands in there to see what's what.

Comment: can you post your  html?

Comment: Added to the post but here just incase:  https://gist.github.com/weblee/6449018

Comment: Can you check if it's working on your **server**? Because the plugin is working just fine on my [server](http://www.must.ee/martin_testing/jqueryupload/) If it's still not working on your server, post your html code so people can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have posted the HMTL now. Im running this on a local Ubuntu server.

Comment: Right now I have don't have an Ubuntu server running so I cannot reproduce the problem. Only thing I can recommend you to do, would be to upload it to your web server and check if it's working then?

Comment: try inspecting the image, if path is correct